# wait for page to load before executing applescipt code in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

I have a code in applescript that automatically fills the webform and I want to wait before the page is fully loaded and then proceed with the javascript filling of the form.

Code:

`tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1`

`activate`

```
open location "http://www."

delay 10

execute javascript "document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_titleDropDownList').value='Mr '"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add that in a `script` tag that waits for the page to load. So at the bottom of the page it'd be something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_titleDropDownList').value='Mr ';
});
</script>
```